2013 Macbook Air automatically boots when power is connected
I have Linux Mint on this machine, no MacOS. As the subject line says, the machine boots up automatically whenever I connect it to power. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?
In case this may matter: I have installed a new battery in this machine and can't remember anymore whether the problem started with this or not.

Can you boot into a macOS environment (external boot disk, or internal recovery tools), run the command nvram auto-boot in Terminal, and report the result?

Try asking on the Linux Stack.

@pion I only get "nvram: Error getting variable - 'auto-boot': (iokit/common) data was not found"

I had to create a systemd service to disable auto-power-on. That fixed it.
Since this turned out to be a Linux issue not an Apple firmware issue, I won't post the details here. Anyone else in the same situation can just ask ChatGPT or Claude how to create said systemd service.
